# Select Top 10, but 11 Results

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have the following query to select top 10. However the result show 11 rows, when I change the select to top 20, it shows 21?

Is there something wrong with the query that is causing this?

```
SELECT TOP 10 Format([DutyDate],"ddd"", ""dd-mmm-yy") AS [Shift Date], Count(Shifts.ID) AS Shifts
FROM Shifts
GROUP BY Format([DutyDate],"ddd"", ""dd-mmm-yy")
ORDER BY Count(Shifts.ID) DESC;
```

Comment: Try adding LIMIT 10 at the end of the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When MS Access processes `TOP`, it puts all ties in for the last value.  In SQL Server, this would be equivalent to `TOP WITH TIES`.  So, if the 11th row has the same count as the 10th, then it is included -- and the 12th and so on, if the counts are the same.

To fix this, you need to include some sort of tie-breaker.  In a `GROUP BY`, that would be the date.  Here is an easy method:

```
ORDER BY Count(Shifts.ID) DESC, MIN(DutyDate)
```